# STM32F722 SPI Data from ICM-20948

Tags: sensor, stm32, c, spi

I am trying to write a driver for the ICM-20948 9 axis sensor by Invensense on my F722 nucleo board. The first thing I am trying to do is see if I can read the device ID (0xEA for the 20948). However, when I check the value of the WHO_AM_I register, all I read is 0. However, when I probe the lines with a Saleae Logic Analyzer, I can clearly see that 0xEA is being sent on the MISO line.

I think there is something wrong with my SPI write and read functions. I have been able to read and write to registers, but things stop working when I try to do this. Any help is greatly appreciated. All relevant functions are listed below:

```
void SPI1_Read(uint8_t *pdata, int size){
    while(size){
        while(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY){}      // wait til not busy
        SPI1->DR = 0;                       // send dummy byte
        while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE)){}  // wait until data received
        *pdata++ = SPI1->DR;                // read int
        size--;
    }
}

void SPI1_Write(uint8_t *pdata, int size){
    int i = 0;
    while(i < size){
        while (!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)){}  // wait until data transmitted
        SPI1->DR = pdata[i];                // send register to write to
        i++;
    }
    while(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE)){}       // wait until TX buffer empty
    while(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_BSY){}          // wait until SPI not in communication
    uint8_t temp = SPI1->DR;                // clear overrun flag by reading DR and SR
    temp = SPI1->SR;
}

void ICM_Read(uint8_t reg, uint8_t data, int size){
    reg |= 0x80;                // 8th bit high for a read
    SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
    SPI1_Write(&reg, 1);
    SPI1_Read(&data, size);
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SPE;
}

void ICM_Write(uint8_t reg, uint8_t data, int size){
    reg &= ~0x80;           // 8th bit low for a write
    SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;
    SPI1_Write(&reg, 1);
    SPI1_Write(&data, size);
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SPE;
}

int ICM_WHOAMI_Ready(void){
    uint8_t whoami;
    ICM_Read(WHO_AM_I_ICM20948, whoami, 1);
    if(whoami == DEVICE_ID){
        return 1;
    }
    else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[image: Saleae Logic Analyzer]

Comment: It might be a problem how the SPI peripheral or GPIO pins are set up which you don't show. Why don't you use the true and tried CubeMX to generate working initialization and then the CubeF7 HAL for the SPI?

Comment: @Justme I am trying to avoid HAL as much as possible in order to learn as much as I can about the hardware.  The only reason I'm doing most of this is to do that so switching to HAL would be kinda pointless for me.  

And I'm almost positive my initialization is correct. You can see the data being sent on the MOSI line and received on the MISO line.  Reading the data in software is my current problem.

Comment: OK, but basically you are spending time rewriting what the HAL already does for you and it is known to work, so you don't have to chase ghosts and figure out at what level your code does not work when it does not work.

Comment: It looks like you're doing 4 bytes of read .. is that intended? I have a feeling that you are seeing the last byte which - also according to the logic trace - is 0x00.

Comment: @TomL. I believe the same thing is happening as well. I checked my initialization function and I definitely set the data width to 8 bits. Do you have any idea why it's adding those extra 2 bytes?

Comment: The `SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;` seems wrong, unless I'm mistaking this enables/disables the whole SPI peripheral, which is a fishy thing to do in run-time unless you have very specialized requirements. Maybe you thought this toggled the slave select pin? Unless you've set the SPI peripheral to do that automatically, you must do it manually.

Comment: Also this line from the Github code is senseless: `(*(uint8_t*)pdata++) = *(volatile uint8_t*)SPI1->DR;`. This is almost certainly wrong - as a rule of thumb: whenever you type out a cast as a beginner, you are introducing a bug. There are very few cases where casts should be used in correctly written programs. In this case I would expect `SPI1->DR` to already be de-referenced and not a pointer. Correct code would look something like `pdata[i] = SPI1->DR;`, inside a well-written for-loop.

Comment: The `SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;` line is used to drive the NSS pin low in hardware NSS mode.  Page 958 of the [reference manual](https://www.st.com/resource/en/reference_manual/dm00305990-stm32f72xxx-and-stm32f73xxx-advanced-armbased-32bit-mcus-stmicroelectronics.pdf) (28.5.5 - NSS Management) talks about it.

Comment: The only reason I used that line `(*(uint8_t*)pdata++) = *(volatile uint8_t*)SPI1->DR;` was because I saw it in some code I was attempting to replicate. The HAL SPI functions also use a lot of typecasts.  I will get rid of the cast though.

Answer (score 0):

The ICM_Read can't return data out of the function, it reads into a local variable.

Comment: I tried declaring the variable `uint8_t whoami` outside the scope of the function, `int ICM_WHOAMI_Ready(void)` but it still doesn't work. How can I edit the function so that it reads into a global variable?

Comment: Sure, just make a global variable and read into that? If you wrote SPI1_Read() yourself, you should be able to change ICM_Read() to be similar so it works when reading into any variable.

Comment: Doesn't have to be global, but it should be valid in the context where you need it. Pass the reference (address), not the value to the ICM_Read function. Something like ICM_Read(uint8_t reg, uint8_t* data, int size)

Comment: @TomL. I added all my files to my Github repo [here](https://github.com/Jpwolfe9912/Autodrone_Test/blob/master/Core/Src).  I changed the ICM_Read function to pass the data by reference but still no luck. In the SPI1_Write() function, I have a line commented out.  For some reason, using that line doesn't work.  Lots of weirdness going on here.

Comment: Well the logic diagram also does not have the chip select go up between transactions. I see you use auto chipselect which you have not configured. Also the SPI read may give out previously received value if you don't clear out the data received before, there can be bytes in the buffers. What use is the enable and disable of the SPI peripheral between transactions? So it looks like you should just copy paste the HAL code for reception or at least learn how it works, because effectively you are just trying to write functions the HAL already has for you.

Comment: @Justme In my Github repo that I linked above, I set the NSS mode as hardware with the line `SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SSM; // CS done by hardware`.  I also understand that what I am doing is fairly redundant and trivial.  However, I would like to get a solid understanding of what I am coding. Trying to recreate the HAL functions helps me do that.  Also, how and where can I clear out the data received buffer?